# Android: design pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns

If I have an activity and want to provide a means to go to related pages what's the preferred method? I have buttons on the page now but it doesn't really look correct. A menu seems wrong too.

EG: Im displaying information about a person's home. The activity displays address, phone and possibly a list of residents in the home. I want the user to be able to go to a map of the home( furniture, etc ), navigation, and possibly a list of comments about the home.

Comment: This is not a design-pattern question, it's a graphical design question, no?

Comment: @Stefan: UI design patterns. Remember that design patterns is a concept borrowed from architecture.

Comment: d'oh :) did not even know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android UI Design Patterns](http://www.androidpatterns.com/)

Comment: Wow - that's a great resource. Thanks!